# Jenkins build is not triggering from XL release

Tags: jenkins, xlrelease

Jenkins build task in XL release is not triggering the Jenkins build,instead it is looking for the last build status of the job run. Can anyone please help how to trigger the jenkins job from XL release ?

Comment: Hi, I am having the same issue you described. Did you come across a resolution?

Answer (score 2):

If there are any errors 'Error 403 No valid crumb was included in the request' and
If you are using jenkins version of 2.176.2 or higher, do the change as mentioned below

https://www.jenkins.io/doc/upgrade-guide/2.176/

So as suggested set the system property hudson.security.csrf.DefaultCrumbIssuer.EXCLUDE_SESSION_ID to true and then restart the jenkins service.